# Is delete(Object) equivalent to calling Object.~Object()

Tags: c++, memory

I have several classes which I connected to [AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/) engine. This engine uses interesting way to allocate objects: It allocates needed amount of memory (possibly with `malloc()`) and when authors propose to use construction like this to create object in this memory:

```
static void Constructor(ObjectType *thisPointer)
{
    new(thisPointer) ObjectType();
}
```

and code like this to destroy object:

```
static void Destructor(ObjectType *thisPointer)
{
     thisPointer->~ObjectType();
}
```

I have several questions:

- Is it correct way to use destructor this way? (Eclipse judges this as a bug) As far as I can understand this code should call destructor without deallocating memory (calling `free()`)
- Is it possible to use `delete(thisPointer)` (or something like it) instead of this construction and is it will be equivalent?  (at least this code gives no errors during compilation and runtime)
- Is there other ways to call destructor without deallocating memory?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After searching for "placement delete" found  [Stroustrup: C++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete) with short answer to question "Is there a "placement delete"?" - "No, but if you need one you can write your own." Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it correct way to use destructor this way?

Yes. You constructed the object in-place using placement-new, and so it must be destroyed with an explicit destructor call (assuming it has a non-trivial destructor).

> Is it possible to use `delete(thisPointer)` (or something like it) instead of this construction and is it will be equivalent?

No. `delete` will attempt to use `operator delete()` to release the memory to the free store; this is only valid if it was allocated with a normal `new` expression (or perhaps an explicit use of `operator new()`).

> Is there other ways to call destructor without deallocating memory?

Not really. Calling the destructor is certainly the clearest and simplest way to call the destructor.

Answer (score 12):

C++ is a bit misleading here:

Construction and memory management are actually completely unrelated processes which C++ munges together in `new` and `delete` for convenience.

However, C++ doesn’t actually have a dedicated syntax to call a constructor on existing memory – to do this, you need to use the “placement `new`” syntax which actually is *not* a conventional `new` at all – i.e., it doesn’t allocate memory.

On the other hand, there *is* a syntax to call the destructor of an object. And your code uses it correctly. And no, using `delete` would not be equivalent, it would free memory in addition to calling a destructor.

Compare this with the [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) class, which has the methods (and their corresponding semantics)

- `allocate` (== `::operator new(sizeof T)`)
- `deallocate` (== `::operator delete(&x)`)
- `construct` (== `new (&x) T()`)
- `destroy` (== `x.~T()`)

These correspond precisely to the different aspects of an object’s lifetime cycle.

Comment: Also, just to emphasise this point once more: `operator new` and `new` are two different things, even though they look so similar. The latter may (!) call the former, but doesn’t always (in the placement-new variant).

Comment: All `new` expressions call some overload of `operator new()`; placement `new` calls one that has no effect.